# yum to install fails on default empty server

Tags: linux, command-line, yum

I used to download Fedora from site X, for example, but lately the site has not updated itself with new packages, therefore commands used to install any of those packages report back with errors as the packages required are not found on the specified server. I would like to learn how to change the default mirror URL inside my install Linux so that it can search freely anywhere the particular packages are available? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your fedora version is supported 14,15, or 16?
usually yum try other mirrors before calling it a fail.
there is a yum plugin called fastest-mirror, install it and this should choose the servers for yum downloads.
if yum can't download the package it self; download it with wget from any fedora hosting site and install it with `rpm -ivh xxxxxx.rpm`
clean the cache typing `yum clean all`
create new cache db typing `yum makecache`